# ¿Cómo agregar imágen en movimiento en jFrame Java?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Tengo una simulación de marquesina en Java, similar a la etiqueta  de HTML5, el código funciona perfectamente sin errores.

```
public class texscroll extends JPanel {
    private int x = 510, y = 25;
    private String string = "Text in moving similary to the tags HTML5 Marquesina (<marquee>).";

    public texscroll() {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN, 15);
        setFont(font);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        setOpaque(false);
        Timer timer = new Timer(14, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                x -= 1;
                if (x == -10 * string.length()) {
                    x = 510;
                }
                repaint();
            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(720, 480);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawString(string, x, y);
    }

}
```

Ahora me gustaría poder agregar o combinar texto e imágenes en movimiento.

```
private String string = "Text in moving similary to the tags HTML5 Marquesina (<marquee>).";
```

¿Cómo puedo llamar a las imágenes localmente `(img/img.png)` y desde la web `URL` para que puedan visualizarse en movimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar imagenes localmente podés hacer así:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Loader {

    public static BufferedImage load(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

y mostrarlas así:

```
String path = "Ruta de imagen";
BufferedImage img = load(path);    
g2d.drawImage(img,  x, y, w, h, null);
```

Para hacerlo por URL, no tengo idea.

Comment: Amigo y dónde agregó la ruta de la imagen `img/img.png` o se selecciona todas las imágenes de alguna carpet específica.

Comment: En donde dice 'path' tendrías que poner la ruta de la imagen.